# Multiple RAIDS on same disks

Tags: raid, raid5, raid1

On a server, I have 3 SATA disks.

I'd like to create a root partition in RAID 1 of 50GB and a data partition in RAID 5 with the remaining spaces on my disks.

There would be 2 different RAID types on the same disks.

Would it be an issue if one of the disks fails? Is it better not to mix RAID types on the same disks ?

Comment: Hardware or software RAID?  If software, what OS?  Anyway, really wouldn't be possible in most hardware controllers, likely only easy under Linux.  In Linux it would be pretty easy to configure though.  I would probably make a 3-way RAID1 so all three drives are identical.  Then your RAID5 on the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

This would definitely not be a recommended setup for a business production system: It adds pointless complexity while unnecessarily increasing your I/O overhead.